# Selenium WebDriver C# - Find element in a classic ASP Web page that includes multiple ASP files

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, asp-classic

I'm trying to write automated test case for a website, which is built using Classic ASP. Each web page (when viewed in the browser) is actually created using multiple ASP files, each of which takes a panel in the overall web page. When trying to use Selenium WebDriver, I can see elements in the main content, but cannot find the elements in the "included ASP files".

For example, the content of the navigation panel is coming from an ASP file; this is achieved by doing something like this...

```
navPanel.Body.Nav.Location.href = "navi.asp"
```

Although the content of the `navi.asp` page shows up when viewed in browser, I'm not able to get its contents using:

```
driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("*"))
```

Could anyone please let me know how I can find the elements that are defined in the "included" asp file?

Here is additional info - the summary of html source as viewed in browser is as follows - as you can see below, there are multiple  elements and by default the *WebDriver* seems to be picking up the elements of the last occurrence of the  tag i.e, contents of the "Content" frame. But, I want to access the elements in "Nav" Frame. How can I do a switch between these frames. I tried using `driver.SwitchTo().Frame("Nav")` but it didn't work obviously because this frame is not visible from within "Content" frame.

```html
<html>
   <head></head>
  <frameset name="Body">
      <html>
        <frame name="**Nav**"></frame>
          <html>
             <form id="**form1**"></form>
          </html>
        </frame>
        <frame name="**Content**">
          <html>
          </html>
        </frame>
      </html>
  </frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: I assume there is an `iframe`. if not please provide the stacktrace as well

Comment: Dud you try using Java-script? If not, try this. `window.frames['frame_name'].document.getElementsByName('element_name');`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter which language is the web page built with, you can use the browser to see what CSS Selector to use...

using Chrome (You can do similar things in different browsers too):

right click on the element that you are interested and press "Inspect element" then go to the Elements tab and right click on the html tag of that element and select "Copy CSS path" and that will copy the proper CSS selector to your clip board.

Look at the picture below:
[image]